# Django and Django channels

Tags: django, django-models, websocket, django-channels

I have one django project, which uses django channels as well.

Now I want to separate django channels into a separate project.

Means, one applicaton will have two django projects,

1. Django for http request. (Django http)
2. Django for websocket request. (Django async)

But, the problem is, if I separated both of these projects, How django async project will use models??

Note:- I want common database between both projects.

Comment: Why do you need to separate them? You are correct about the models (and everything else, actually). I don't think that is the intended or supported use-case - django-channels should live together with the Django project code

Comment: In our production server, gunicorn is serving http request and daphne is serving websocket request, Problem is:- django backend codebase is of huge size, and we have one common codebase between gunicorn and daphne. That Means, gunicorn and daphne have separate instances of same codebase.So, daphne will have Code of rest APIs as well, which I don't think is necessary. So that's why I want to separate the projects.

Comment: I see. Well, that's actually the intended deployment setup. There should be no issue with codebase of any size from the operational viewpoint.

Comment: So, can't we separate django http and django async Code?